# Excel string not working

Tags: excel, vba

Hello guys I am completely stumped as to why this bit of code is not working. Can anybody help?

```
Sub test()

Dim RpDate As Variant
Dim x As String

RpDate = InputBox("Enter Date", "Date")
If RpDate = "" Then Exit Sub

x = Day(RpDate)

MsgBox x

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "Not Working"?  The code works for me.

Comment: Works for me too.

Comment: I get a run time error 13 type mismatch message with the x = Day(RpDate) line highlighted when I select debug. I have a blank new workbook with just this macro.

Comment: @Rdster I tried your suggestion and I still get the same error. I can't see why this wouldn't work for me but it isn't.

Comment: Maybe `x = CStr(Day(RpDate))` ?

Comment: @Rdster Same error :/

Comment: What are you trying to enter as a date?

Comment: I just figure out why it wasn't working. I am such an idiot. I was entering 11/31/16 which doesn't exist. I'm so embarrassed thank you all for helping me so quickly!

Comment: @D. Cruz you could try the code I have below, it will only accept `InputBox` with valid date values. So Nov 31st would throw an error

Answer (score 1):

You could force the `InputBox` to allow only `Date` type valid values, try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub InputBoxDateFormat()

Dim RpDate As Date
Dim x As Integer

' InputBox that allows only dates
RpDate = Application.InputBox("Enter Date", "Date", FormatDateTime(Date, vbShortDate), Type:=1)

' "Cancel" was selected
If RpDate = 0 Then Exit Sub

x = Day(RpDate)
MsgBox x

End Sub
```